# What tools can create 2-D and 3-D animations I can use in an iPad app?

Tags: ios, animation

I would like to create 2-D or 3-D animations using a tool, then use these animations in an iPad app that I'm writing.  What tools exist that can create such animations?

Can any of the Adobe products create files which can be integrated with an iPad app?  I know that Flash can be used to create animations, but support for this is limited on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL can be used for 2D/3D graphics and animations and Cocos2D for 2D graphics and animations. The only thing I know about Adobe is that Flex can be used to make iPhone apps. Maybe you can import After Effects or Flash files into that?